# Kill port on remote server with ssh

Tags: centos

I want to kill specific port on remote host with below command:

```
ssh username@remoteip "fuser -k 2323/tcp"
```

but got `fuser: command not found` error. This command available on remote machine.

Any idea?

My Linux distribution: Centos

Comment: Where is that command available on remote machine?

Comment: @RalfFriedl Hi, thanks man, you gave me a clue. fuser command available on /sbin on remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @RalfFriedl comment, I checked server and found fuser command located on /sbin. in this situation we must pass /sbin/fuser from ssh.